# How to import talend Job from one talend version to other talend version

Tags: salesforce, version, talend, tls1.2, migrate

I Have developed a Job in Talend V5.5 which was working fine but Now I want to migrate the whole Job into Talend Job v6.1.1 as using Talend V5.5 I am facing error of TLS 1.0 and it does not support Java V1.8. I have tried to import the Job from V 5.5 to V 6.1.1 but was not able to do the same.

Please guide me step by step solution will be a bonus for me.

Thanks in advance and appreciate the  help.

Amit Singh

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this argument to JVM arguments of your job :
    -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2

Comment: I already tried this option and still I can see that it is using TLS 1.0. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

What are you doing that requires TLS 1.0?

You may be better off moving to a higher TLS version.